S3 replication not triggering notification
I have a source S3 bucket configured to replicate all objects to another S3 bucket (destination) in the same region. Replication is unidirectional (source-to-destination only) and delete markers are not replicated. This setup makes for a perfect S3 backup solution (for my needs).
Replication has been working flawlessly, but I would like to get notified about failed replication operations (if any), which is not working.

Replication doesn't use any filters--all objects get replicated.
I have metrics and RTC (Replication Time Control) enabled on the replication configuration (aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration)
S3 bucket notifications (aws_s3_bucket_notification) are configured to send "s3:Replication:*" events from the source S3 bucket to a Lambda function.
Lambda function is set up to allow invocations from source S3 bucket (aws_lambda_permission).

I can confirm that the communication between the S3 bucket and the Lambda is correctly set up, because when I add "s3:ObjectCreated:*" to the aws_s3_bucket_notification configurations, those events do trigger the Lambda. However, when I leave only the "s3:Replication:*" events, which are the only events I'm actually interested in, the Lambda never gets triggered--I'm testing this by uploading new objects to the source bucket, which do get replicated to the destination bucket, only without triggering any of those "s3:Replication:*" events.
Thanks in advance.

It appears that the Replication Events in Amazon S3 relate to Replication Time Control (S3 RTC) - Amazon Simple Storage Service:

Using Amazon S3 event notifications to track replication objects
You can track replication time for objects that did not replicate within 15 minutes by monitoring specific event notifications that S3 Replication Time Control (S3 RTC) publishes. These events are published when an object that was eligible for replication using S3 RTC didn't replicate within 15 minutes, and when that object replicates after the 15 minute threshold.
Replication events are available within 15 minutes of enabling S3 RTC. Amazon S3 events are available through Amazon SQS, Amazon SNS, or AWS Lambda. For more information, see Amazon S3 Event Notifications.

If you are not using Replication Time Control, then you will not receive any Replication Events.
See also: Monitoring progress with replication metrics and S3 Event Notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service
